# From excel to datatables

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, export

I want to export data from my excel tables to datatable but don't know how should i put the data to the DataTables. Can someone help me with it?

My code would be:

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(userSelectedFilePath2);
Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

DataTable excelTb = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i <= xlRange.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
     for (int j = 1; j <= xlRange.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
          excelTb.Columns.Add(xlRange.Cells[0,j].Value2.ToString());
          foreach (DataRow extb in excelTb.Rows)
          {
              DataRow newDataRow = excelTb.NewRow();
              // Here should be something to put data in DataTable
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why not use OleDbConnection to Excel?

Comment: because OleDb can't read more than 255 chars in cells, so i try with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Comment: I really found Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel difficult and not so "userfriendly". I would suggest you to use [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @NaNNy: i'll try later EPPlus, now i will give a try with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  for (int row = 0; row < xlRange.Rows.Count; row++)
    {
        DataRow dataRow = null;
        if (row != 0) dataRow = excelTb.NewRow();

        for (int col = 0; col < xlRange.Columns.Count; col++)
        {
            if (row == 0) //Headers
            {
                excelTb.Columns.Add(xlRange.Cells[row + 1, col + 1].Value2.ToString());
            }
            else //Data rows
            {
                dataRow[col] = xlRange.Cells[row + 1, col + 1].Value2.ToString();

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm typing from my cell phone on the go =). When I get to work I'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to deal with xlsx and xlsm files use epplus, its indefinitely faster than interop. It is a package for reading / writing excel-files. Additionally, it has a very nice license and cost nothing.

For your datatable you could go along this lines (vb.net codE)

```
     Dim tbl As New DataTable
     for cols = 0 to j 'you have to define the columns first
         tbl.Columns.Add()
     next

    for cols = 0 to j
       for rows = 0 to your_rowcount
            Dim row = tbl.NewRow
'Here is the critical part: iterate over the worksheet, and take each value from the sheet. put the value into the datatable. The datatable needs to get a new row for each worksheet.row
    Dim value = yourworksheet.cells(cols+1,rows+1).value
     row(cols)=Value
   next
next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void grabData(string filename)
            {
                    // Clear DataTaable before generating new Table Data/
                    ds.Clear();

                    // Connection String to the previously selected file. 
                    // HDR=Yes advises that spreadsheet has columns. 

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(
                    "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + filename +
                    ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\"");


                    // The criteria required to Build DataTable. Select specific columns                 //from spreadsheet where teh Site Statuse is LIVE.
                    string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [YOURTABLE]";

                    // The Command that we will use with our DataAdapter.
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, con);

                    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(ds, "YourTable");


            }
```

Comment: OP said that he can't use OleDB because it can't read more than 255 chars in cells

Answer (score 0):

Read the data from the worksheet into a 2D object array like this:

```
//Convert from interop object to native C# object, indexed 1 to length
object[,] data = (object[,])xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Value2;
```

Now you can add a cell to the DataRow like this:

```
   for (int row = 1; row < data.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
    {
        DataRow newDataRow = excelTb.NewRow();
        newDataRow["AStringColumn"] = data[row,1].ToString();
        newDataRow["ADoubleColumn"] = Convert.ToDouble(data[row, 2]);
        //repeat for each column OR replace with a column loop and use newDataRow[col] = data[row, col].ToString();

        excelTb.Rows.Add(newDataRow);
    }
```

note that the double array is indexed from 1 and not 0 like arrays normally are in C#.

Comment: BTW - you do also have to add the columns to the DataTable right in the beginning.

Comment: can you show me in your code, because i'm trying to to it, got many errors

Comment: What errors? Add columns like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I got NullRefereceException, can you show me complete code how to do it?

Comment: This really is basically the complete code. At what point did you get a null reference exception. You have to be very specific when asking for help with errors, you should provide the line the error occurred on, what the error said and the values (from the debugger) of important variables at the time of the error.